# System.Data.DataTable in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Does anyone know if **System.Data.DataTable** is now supported in Silverlight 4 beta? In the past I’ve used this for databinding in ASP.NET and WinForm projects where the UI and objects needs to be constructed at runtime. If not, is it in the road map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeplex [here](http://slbindabledatagrid.codeplex.com/) have developed a lightweight datatable that can get you by in some situations

Answer (score 3):

No this is not in SL4 and is unlikely to ever make it into later versions either.  It represents an older approach to data access.  In SL you would be expected to integrate with Entity Framework via WCF for this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation for DataTable in Mono . I tried to port it to Silverlight once but it has a lot of dependencies in Xml so I couldn't port the whole things.

Yes. It would be great if we can get light-version of it.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentOne have an implementation of the DataTable