# How to use DataTable in silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datatable, telerik-grid

Is System.Data.DataTable  supported in Silverlight 4.0 ?
I saw this link : [DataTable in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809363/system-data-datatable-in-silverlight-4)

I need to get the data from datagridview. using that data i have to prepare a radbarchart.

Instead if using datatable can we use list or any thing.

Can any body tell me how can get the data from datagridview.